# IIF Statement in SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Tags: ssms-2014

I’m using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and trying to run code with an `IIF` statement.

The syntax is correct as far as I can see but I keep getting an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

The code is below

```
SELECT 
    [Name], [Street], [City],
    IIF([Country] = 'UK', 'UK', 'Overseas') AS Country
FROM 
    [dbo].TblAddress
```

Comment: Check what **version** of the database **engine** you're running against by using `SELECT @@VERSION`. The Management Studio (the GUI tool) might have a much newer version than the engine you're connecting to, but it's the **engine's** version that determines most of the features being available (or not). `IIF` was introduced in SQL Server **2012** - if you're running against an older engine, you won't be able to use that

Comment: Thanks, the Select @@Version was useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is correct.

It now depends on which version of SQL Server you have rather than which version of SQL Server Management Studio.

For example running

```
SELECT 
    [Name], [Street], [City],
    IIF([Country] = 'UK','UK','Overseas') AS Country
FROM 
    [dbo].TblAddress
```

on SQL Server 2012 or higher would work (SQL Server 2014 in the below example)

[image: SQL Server 2014]

But on SQL Server 2008 or lower it returns:
(SQL Server 2008 R2 is Version 10.50...)

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

[image]

This is because `IIF` is only available in SQL Server 2012 onwards

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql

The version of SQL Server Management Studio doesn't matter.

Comment: It looks like I have SQL SERVER 2008, so that means I can't use IIF?

Comment: Correct. Use CASE instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql